# Realtime line chart animation - new values jump, because initial value (at the beginning at the animation) is far away

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've started using chart.js today. I'm making a simple data visualizer and I use chart.js for that. It's a live, "stream-like" line-chart.

My problem is that when I add a new element to the dataset, the amplitude of the animation for that new element is too large, because it's starting far away from the last position. I don't know how the initial position is calculated now, but it's not very nice.

For example my last 3 values for a dataset are something like 122, 123, 121, then I add 122, but the animation start from 100, then it goes up to 122, so it makes a huge "jump".

I think it could be much better if the initial value (at the beginning of the animation) was the value of last-but-one element (starting from 121 in the previous example), so it would start from the same position, spanning a much smaller distance. Can I achieve that somehow with some settings / options?

Here's my initial chart config. What could I do to improve the animation?

```
const _chart = new Chart(
    _canvas,
    {
        type: "line",
        data: {
            labels: [firstValue.timeStamp],
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: [firstValue.electric],
                    label: "Electric Energy Consumption (W)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 220, 1)",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 220, 0.2)",
                    tension: 0.2
                },
                {
                    data: [firstValue.gas],
                    label: "Gas Consumption (m³)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(220, 220, 0, 1)",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(220, 220, 0, 0.2)",
                    tension: 0.2
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }
    }
);
```

Here's a live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/soadzoor/kfmcazj1/10/

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm experiencing the same problems

Comment: @RickGroenewegen I ended up using another library called billboard.js. It's not perfect either, but handles this scenario much nicer.